# Disable Lazy Evaluation in QEMU

Tags: lazy-evaluation, qemu

Is it possible to disable lazy evaluation in QEMU (User-Mode)?

I found no flags for it when running qemu-i386.
Looking at the Code i found the function: 
`static target_ulong disas_insn(DisasContext *s, CPUState *cpu)`
in *target/i386/translate.c* which converts one instruction into a host instruction. Within this function, the function:
`static void gen_compute_eflags(DisasContext *s)`
is used to generate eflags for specific instructions (that will need them).

My first idea would be to add the `gen_compute_eflags()` to every instruction, i wonder if there is a more effective and less error-prone way to do this.

Comment: When you want add code that works for all instructions, add it right before `next_byte` label in `disas_insn`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to achieve? There is no easy way to somehow disable the optimisation away of the flag-register codegen when the flag value is never used before it is overwritten, but I don't know why you would want to do that. The optimisation makes execution faster and QEMU does it in only the places where it is safe (ie where the flag value we don't compute is never used by the guest and not visible to the user via the debug stub).

Comment: i am comparing register dumps from qemu to register dumps of a native execution of the same binary. the eflags register is not the same at one point, my guess is that this is due to the lazy evaluation of qemu. i am using the -singlestep and nochain option for the dumps

Comment: eflags registers being incorrect in register dumps would be a QEMU bug: the optimisation is supposed to provide the eflags values at any point where they're visible, including in register dumps. That is possible, but seems unlikely (it's more likely that it's a legitimate divergence between native and QEMU for some other reason). If you can provide a reproduce case (on the most recent QEMU from git, ideally) to the qemu-devel mailing list we could look at it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply! i had a look at it and found out that this was due to the flag being undefined for this specific instruction